# How to provide read and write to ColumnTransofrmer programatically in Hibernate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, hibernate, encryption, aws-secrets-manager

I am using AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT function of mysql which takes key as a parameter. However, I don't want to hardcode the key at application level, nor do I want to store it in application.properties file as I want to have the key in a different server. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom `MetadataContributor` that can change the read/write mappings of a property programmatically.

```
public class MyMetadataContributor implements MetadataContributor {
    public void contribute(InFlightMetadataCollector metadataCollector, IndexView jandexIndex) {
        List<Selectable> selectables = metadataCollector.getEntityBindingMap().get("fqn.to.my.Entity")
            .getProperty("myProperty")
            .getValue()
            .getSelectables();
        ((Column) selectables.get(0)).setCustomRead(...);
        ((Column) selectables.get(0)).setCustomWrite(...);
    }
}
```