# Can I handle NaN as NULL in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, bigdecimal

I have some columns with NaN values in my Postgres database. We're handling money so all of my entities are BigDecimals, which can't accomodate NaN.

Is there a setting or something on JPA or Hibernate where I can tell it "Treat any NaNs as if they were NULLS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that for individual columns with `@ColumnTransformer` and can do it programmatically through a `MetadataContributor` (see [How to provide read and write to ColumnTransofrmer programatically in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446798/how-to-provide-read-and-write-to-columntransofrmer-programatically-in-hibernate/69618793#69618793)), but it's not possible to do this globally.

However, if you have NaN in your database, something is wrong already, as you are saving the values with some float/double type. So IMO you should first migrate the data `update tbl set col = null where is_nan(col)` and then switch to `alter table tbl alter column col set datatype numeric(19,3)` or something like that.